# Laravel 8 Eloquent upsert inserting new records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to understand Laravel 8's new feature `upsert`.

Here is my sample table:

```
flights
id (primary key and auto Inc)
departure
destination
price
```

In my code:

```
App\Models\Flight::upsert([
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
    ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
], ['departure', 'destination']);
```

This is the sample table from Laravel documentation and it has one key id.

I want to update the record if both `departure` and `destination` are matched but these fields are not unique.

Every time I run the code, it inserts a new record but does not update. How to get `upsert` working?

Do I need to make both `departure` and `destination` unique or will it work without making them unique?

Also if I need to make both fields unique then how can I do it in migration?

Comment: The second argument to `upsert` is an array of **unique column names**. The 3rd argument would be values to update if a match was found, otherwise the raw data is inserted from the first argument. So, yes, if you are going to go this route, `departure` and `destination` would have to be unique, but that doesn't make sense to me for Flight data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need pass the unique key in the second parameter of `upsert` which is the id column and primary key of the table, the sample data would be

```
App\Models\Flight::upsert([
    ['id'=> 1, 'departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
    ['id'=> 2, 'departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
], ['id']);
```

Comment: Thanks but as you can see I dont have ID while I edit , can we do upsert without ID

Comment: @Mr.SH Basically there should a unique identifier for each record, if id is in database and you don't pass it in your request then how would you or laravel know which row to update in database, So I would strongly suggest to add id in your form or request. Like we normally do for update a single record in database which is determined by the unique identifier of record.

Comment: If you have a column, such as 'departure' that is not specified as unique will this still work? I have a similar upsert query that doesn't update but does create a new record despite me setting the second param as the non-unique col name...

Comment: @raison the second param in my opinion should be unique to identify single record to update, if your second param is not unique then it may update multiple row with same data or add new rows in case if not found

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem, i make the second parameter as "composite unique".

Add this to migration

```
$table->unique(['departure','destination']);
```

The problem should gone

#### Documentation

Starting in Laravel 9.x, the [Eloquent documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts) was updated to mention the fact that `upsert()` depends on DB unique constraint:

> All databases except SQL Server require the columns in the second argument of the upsert method to have a "primary" or "unique" index. In addition, the MySQL database driver ignores the second argument of the upsert method and always uses the "primary" and "unique" indexes of the table to detect existing records.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this solved my issue. I have to set the columns as unique to make `upsert` function work

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Apparently, the second argument for upsert is useless. The upsert uses the primary/unique key to check for unique values in the table.

Comment: Good answer. Added quote from the docs (only starting in 9.x) confirming need for DB unique constraint

Answer (score 0):

You need the third parameter for the column to be updated.

```
Flight::upsert([
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
    ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
], ['departure', 'destination'], ['price']);
```

Comment: This still creates new entries.

Comment: I have the same issue